# How to create mydomain.com/name and point it to mywebsite.com/page?

Tags: url, redirect, dns, cname

How can I create mydomain.com/**name** which is domain only (not hosted) and point it to a page on a hosted website e.g. mywebsite.com/webpage?

I have access to the DNS of mydomain.com and would need to create mydomain.com/**name** ... and have access to DNS of mywebsite.com (limited access to the hosting.

My research suggests that /name is handled in the hosted environment, but looking for other possibilities.

Is this possible with DNS, CNAME, etc.? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, DNS can only handle `mydomain.com`. If you want to redirect on a specific path, such as `/name` you have to have a web server running that can respond to requests and redirect appropriately. Some DNS providers has this built-in and will provide it, without a hosting package.

But everything after the first `/` in a URL no longer has anything to do with DNS.

Comment: Thank you colde, that clarifies this item for me.